# Jenkins without public page

Tags: jenkins

I want to install Jenkins in a dedicated server, with other dev tools. This server will be public, no VPN.

By default, although the security is enabled, in the public landed page you can see all jobs even download artifacts.

Is possible remove this page and don't show anything to no logged people?
How to do it?

Regards

Comment: I love people that down vote a question and don't explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Manage jenkins > Configure global security* enable *Matrix-based security* and remove all rights from *anonymous*.

That way only the login form will be shown when not authenticated.

---

If you google for *restrict access for jenkins* you quickly find the *Securing jenkins* [wiki entry](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Securing+Jenkins), there is alot of information.

Comment: Thx @dominik-gebhart I was using "Logged-in users can do anything" so I supposed that only logged people can access to Jenkins information. Call me crazy, but for me was logic.

Comment: Yeah it sounds like this, i generally check the `?` next to options, in this case it reveals that *In this mode, every logged-in user gets full control of Jenkins. The only user who won't have full control is* **anonymous user, who only gets read access**.  Glad its solved tho.